# PowerShell Remoting to many servers across domains

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am DBA. I am trying to write bunch of scripts that I could execute from one central server. Ideal would be to send all the scripts from central server to say 50+ servers across multiple win domains (for databases management purposes).

The problem I am running into is - security. Seems like PowerShell Remoting is the way to go. But when I send a script to another server, I get 'not digitally signed' error.

I could 'self sign'. But that cert if only trusted on local machine. So that option is out.

Maybe Certificate Authority is a way to go. Or adding trusted hosts. I just have no clue on this one, so if you know any blog posts or how to do this - it would be big help.

Comment: what do you mean with 'send a script to another server'?

Comment: I have bunch of functions already written. To use those functions I have to RDP into each server and run locally. Since local and remote sessions are totally separate and don't see each other's variable, i think the way to do it, is to send the WHOLE script over to remote server over remote session.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a security risk, but there's always the possibility of setting the execution policy to RemoteSigned, keeping a local repository on each server and calling those as needed via PS-Remoting. I don't like that idea one bit though.

If you are doing remote execution, you will need to sign your scripts. A detailed step by step can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/17/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-2-of-2.aspx). It even covers deploying the cert via GPO so that it's domain trusted.

Answer (score 0):

I would use PowerShell remoting. This would allow you to run it as remote commands instead of remote scripts. If you catch the bottom of [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/new-remoting-features-in-powershell-2.0/) SimpleTalk article, after "Persistent Sessions". It shows the option of executing a set of commands against each server instead of the script. This should prevent having to deal with the remote signed issue and provide a little more control.

The only thing to deal with on remote sessions is your credentials. I have not tried this on multiple domains but a few stand-alone servers.